# How can I verify the following source code? What is missing?

Tags: testnets

I tried to verify it [here](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x302cc16165b3ae82643ac62a8b77ba48b1f03fe1).

With the following information (main net):

```
0x302cc16165b3ae82643ac62a8b77ba48b1f03fe1
LeonardoDaVinciToken
v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52
Enabled
```

Contract Soure Code is [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x302cc16165b3ae82643ac62a8b77ba48b1f03fe1#code).

My testnet deploy is [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x59ba93e7f76b71deda14b4b171905aeeabe68e31#code).

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: disabling or enabling optimizations can be the case, when a source code is compiled is with optimizations, its slightly changed when it's without optimizations. but this won't harm the functionality

Answer (score 1):

Just checked and it is indeed verified.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x302cc16165b3ae82643ac62a8b77ba48b1f03fe1#code